# Specify page name via php

Tags: php

If anyone can help me here that would be great.  I reviewed a client's site files that named each page by using php to take the filename of the page, and then specified the page name at the top of the file.

For example, if the filename of the file is "index.php", the top of the file would automatically receive a code snippet that looked roughly like this:

```
<?php
  page_name == 'index';
?>
```

I know that's not the code, but that's unfortunately what I remember of it.  If anyone can clarify it for me, it would be greatly appreciated.

Additionally, the site used this functionality to then apply the page's name as a class to the body tag (which was part of the head include), and define the title (also in the head).  If you know how this was done, that's where I'm headed, so your expertise would be appreciated.

Thanks again.

Comment: Check this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/get-current-file-name/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? rawr.php:

```
<body class="<?php echo pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_FILENAME); ?>">

</body>
```

gives

```
<body class="rawr">

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the file name, use this PHP code:

```
<?php $pageName = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '.php'); ?>
```

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is the filename of the currently executing script, relative to the document root, so it may include path information in addition to the filename. Running it through `basename()` with the `.php` parameter will give you the trailing name component of the path, minus the `.php` suffix.

To use it as a class of the body tag, include this:

```
<body class="<?php echo $pageName ?>">
```

Putting it in the `<title>` is very similar:

```
<title><?php echo $pageName ?></title>
```

Comment: Thanks Kenny.  And how would I then reference the pageName in an external functions file?

Comment: @theFreelancer If you want to call a function that's in another php file, you can `require_once('functionsFile.php')` and then call the function, passing `$pageName` as a parameter, like so: `functionName($pageName)`

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is a combination of Kenny's answer:

```
<?php $pageName = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '.php'); ?>
```

With setting up the HTML `title` to the page name as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php print $pageName;?></title>
</head>
<body>
...
```